# Are these undefined checking identical in behavior?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I've seem different approaches for (strict equality) checking for `undefined`:

- `if (something === undefined)`
- `if (typeof something === 'undefined')`
- `if (something === void 0)`
- *and probably others*

In a *happy scenario* their behavior is the same. In other words, they all work.

But, considering all the quirk corners of JavaScript, are they truly identical in behavior?

*If yes*, why people choose other approaches rather than the first? Is it some sort of legacy or misconception? Because the first one it's obviously the most clear in both readability and intention demonstration.

Comment: They are not identical, the first tests strict for the undefined keyword, the second for a string, and `void 0` returns undefined, so it's the same as the first one.

Comment: @adeneo, identical **in behavior**. What I meant if it is safe to assume that they always will return the same result.

Comment: They are not identical in behaviour either, the first one and the last one would throw an error if `something` was not defined.

Comment: @adeneo, yup, that is exactly the kind of thing that I wanted to know when I asked this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if (something === undefined)` is the standard normal way

`typeof something === 'undefined'` on a declared variable is mostly an overdefensive solution dating from the time where you could change `window.undefined`. If you don't know if your variable is declared, it has the advantage of not raising an error but I don't think a legit code should support the case of a variable whose declarative state is unknown.

`void 0` (or [void anything](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.2)) is a normalized way to get `undefined` so it's equivalent to the first one but useless.

Comment: `typeof something === 'undefined'` is not overdefensive, if your variable might not be declared. There's a type `'undefined'` and a value `undefined` AFAIK. And the value `undefined` is of type `'undefined'`

Comment: @elclanrs Good point. Edited. It's hard to see a legit case where you need to support a variable which might not be declared, thoug.

Comment: I agree, I never use it, but it has a legit use.

Comment: So I can use `typeof` with an undeclared variable and it doesn't raise a `ReferenceError`, as it would normally do when accessing it. Not sure when this would be useful, but good to know anyway (:

Answer (score 0):

1. Literally `undefined`
2. Test for existence, as in "variable not declared".
3. Same as `undefined`. Older version of the JS standard let you change the value of `undefined` as it's just a variable. `void 0` is `undefined`, it's safer.

An extra one:

1. `if (x == null)`. Tests for `undefined` **and** `null` because `undefined == null` but remember, `undefined !== null`

In JavaScript there's a type `'undefined'` and a value `undefined`. The value `undefined` is of type `'undefined'`.